# How to use debug package in SailsJs

Tags: node.js, debugging, sails.js

I am working on a SailsJs application and used console.log for debugging purposes. I am trying to use npm package debug for this purpose.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug
```

However, after reading its explanation and examples, I have not idea how to use it:

"With debug you simply invoke the exported function to generate your debug function, passing it a name which will determine if a noop function is returned, or a decorated console.error, so all of the console format string goodies you're used to work fine. A unique color is selected per-function for visibility."

I can not make sense of this.

For example, I have UserController.js and I need to have enable debugging. 
Should I use or something else?

```
var debug=require('debug')('UserController');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Exactly. You should provide a name for debug package and than you will be able to use it as a function.

For example in controller:

```
var debug = require('debug')('AnyName');

module.exports = {
  someAction: function(req, res) {
    debug(req);
  }
};
```